# IIS problems after installing July'18 Updates

Tags: iis, asp-classic, com, activex, windows-update

We are experiencing the following problems after installing the July'18 updates in our servers running Windows 2012 and Windows 2016:

1) We can no longer restart the www service. The service locks in "stopping" mode forever.

2) We can no longer instantiate .NET .DLLs (interop) in classic ASP using server.createobject. We receive the error 0x800A01AD "ActiveX component can't create object". I've read some workarounds at other forums to change IIS Anonymous Authentication to "Application pool identity" but it didn't resolve the problem.

We could only fix both problems after uninstalling ALL the July'18 KB's: KB4284815, KB4338815, KB4338424, KB4338419, KB4054566.

Other questions I found here did not solve or even mention the www restart problem, that also started after the July updates.

Comment: This reads like a bug report to submit to Microsoft--not a programming question to submit to StackOverflow.  If you have a programming question, I would start by phrasing your post as a question.

Comment: Did you not see this? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51289285/692942

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly instantiate 32-bit COM objects in classic ASP after installing Windows Update KB4340558?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289285/how-do-i-properly-instantiate-32-bit-com-objects-in-classic-asp-after-installing)

Comment: Yes, I saw this question but I believe my problem is not quite the same. Firstly their workaround did not work for our windows boxes. Secondly we have an additional problem that is the www service restart stalling. All of them started after this month's updates. I posted it to Microsoft and here, in the hope for some working workaround.

Comment: @GuilhermeRudnitzki point 2. is definitely the same issue. As for point 1. that’s not a suitable question for [so], you would be better asking on [sf] or contacting Microsoft as stated previously.

Comment: Thank you, @Lankymart. I followed your recommendation and posted my question at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/922189/iis-problems-after-installing-july18-updates).
BTW, the www service restart and the .net issues seems to be related. Please check [this thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches)

Comment: @GuilhermeRudnitzki thanks for letting us know. Also, never suggested they weren't related just that this isn't the place to post them and it seems as though there is quite a detailed thread on iis.net already.

Comment: I believe that the [detailed thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches) on iis.net is the one I mentioned in my last comment. Anyway, I think that this post maybe useful for developers either, since these problems affects .net users. BTW, Microsoft has released [this patch](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4345397) for the www service "stopping" bug.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is aware of the .NET DLL access denied errors and is still working on a solution: https://support.microsoft.com/am-et/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday Microsoft finally published a resolution for the "ActiveX component can't create object" error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update. I tested it in Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 2016 and it worked OK.

Comment: This fixed the problem on Windows 10 machine as well.