# ActiveX component can't create object occurred in w3wp.exe

Tags: iis, asp-classic, activex

I am currently having an issue with a classic ASP application I am working on and from what I can tell it might be due to something related to IIS.

It started out with me getting the error:

```
"An unhandled exception ('ActiveX component can't create object') occurred in 
w3wp.exe[XXXX]."
```

I tried googling, but failed to find anything that could solve my issue.

So I tried to create a small .vbs application. To see if it had anything to do with the component that is used for the "createObject()" method.

```
dim test 
set test = createObject("System.Collections.Sortedlist")
test.add 1, "value 1"
test.add 2, "value 2"
MsgBox(test(1))
```

And the file ran as it should.

I've tried running the application using both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017.

After I noticed that it sad "Occurred in the w3wp.exe" I tried reinstalling IIS to see if that would change anything, but sadly it has not had any effect.

Update: I am using Windows 10 personally and running the site of my own PC for testing purposes.

["Access Denied" errors and applications with COM activation fail after installing July 2018 Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly instantiate 32-bit COM objects in classic ASP after installing Windows Update KB4340558?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289285/how-do-i-properly-instantiate-32-bit-com-objects-in-classic-asp-after-installing)

Comment: There was a July update that messed with how .Net Dlls talk to COM through IIS, I’d start there.

Comment: @Lankymart From what I can gather from the post you linked, it is unable to help me. As I am running Windows 10, so the updates they mention from what I gather don't relate to me. Since it says they where for Windows 8,1 and Server 2012. I was also already running the Application Pool Identity as "ApplicationPoolIdentity" as they mention for a possible fix/work around. I will however try and roll my windows 10 system back by one update and see if that helps.

Comment: While they “appear” to be the OS affected, it’s an assumption. Both issues are with running .Net COM exposed DLLs through COM in IIS, that is enough of a coincidence for me.

Comment: This issue absolutely is relevant on Windows 10, this question helped me configure a server at the weekend.  If you read through all the answers there are three separate settings mentioned, which all need to be correct

Comment: I'll give it another look in some time. Removing the update ended up fucking my work computer and I've only started setting it back up today after a complete reinstall