# Acrobat FDF Toolkit Compatibility on Server 2016

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2016, fdf

So, I know this is atrocious, but can I expect to get the [Acrobat FDF Toolkit](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html), for which the latest documentation I can find was released in October 2003, to work on Windows Server 2016?

From the SysWOW64 directory, I have run regsvr32 for the binary, which I have placed in it's own directory in the root of the C drive.  It indicated success, and I can see evidence of that in the registry.  However, when I try to navigate to a simple ASP Classic page that utilizes this library, it fails on this line:

```
Set FdfAcX = Server.CreateObject("FdfApp.FdfApp")
```

with the error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'

ActiveX component can't create object
```

[This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/201740/cannot-create-object-error-when-browsing-asp-pages) claims this error is induced when the IUSR_*computer* and IWAM_*computer* do not have read permissions to the directory of the binary.  I believe I have provided those accounts that permission (though the only ones I could find in my case are IUSR_*domain* and IWAM_*domain*... ?), but the error persists.

What steps do I need to take to resolve this error?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with the FDF toolkit? For basic form filling, you might find it easier to just use XFDF instead of FDF and then you can use standard XML tools. You really only need the FDF Toolkit for more complicated tasks like adding images to button faces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-server-createobject-fails-for-com-dll)

Comment: Really, all the code is doing is populating 3 fillable fields on a pdf template.  Think of a typical "Certificate of Achievement".  It populates variations of those templates with name, date, and an ID.  We know there must be better ways to do it, but we were not prepared to re-write the code and were hoping to just get this working for the time being.  I will check out XFDF though.

Comment: No promises, but you may find the answer in this question.  There was a windows update about a month ago which affected a lot of old third party components in Classic ASP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289285/how-do-i-properly-instantiate-32-bit-com-objects-in-classic-asp-after-installing

Comment: I would give that a try, but we are using Server 2016.

Comment: It's relevant to Server 2016.  I followed those steps for another component on a 2016 server and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you are only filling in fields on a pdf template, you can do it without creating an object. You can do by just kind of filling out the form.

TheFdfPdf.asp: The variables within the parenthesis are names of your fields on your pdf form.

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.fdf"
PdfTemplateUrl = "http://TheDomain.com/pdfs/ThePdf.pdf"  
SomeTextValue = "This is a test value for some field on a pdf form"
SomeNumber = 789
SomOtherValue = "Groovy"
%>
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF
<<
/Fields [
<< /T (SomeTextValue) /V (<%=SomeTextValue%>) >>
<< /T (SomeNumber) /V (<%=SomeNumber%>) >>  
<< /T (SomOtherValue) /V (<%=SomOtherValue%>) >>
]
/F (<%=PdfTemplateUrl%>) >>
>>
endobj
trailer 
<<  /Root 1 0 R  >> 
%%EOF
```

Comment: That's good to know, but when I try and do this, editing the file path and variables to correspond with my pdf and it's fields, then access the page, I get prompted to download an fdf file named _TheFdfPdf.asp.fdf_, rather than the file specified in `PdfTemplateUrl`.  What am I doing wrong?