# Classic ASP Server.CreateObject permission denied

Tags: asp-classic, permission-denied

I have written a com object that several classic ASP sites are using to access our database. We have 1 site that is on its own server that works flawlessly. We have another server that is hosting 2 sites, but on that server 1 of the sites works fine but the other gets an error when creating the com object.

Here is the text from the error message: The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object.

I immediately assumed this was because the account that the app pool is using doesn't have access to the location where the com object is located, and everything I've found online agrees with that. I made sure that the account does have full access but it did not help. I even tried running the not working site on the same app pool as the site that does work. This still didn't fix the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install Windows Update July 2018?

Comment: This is permission issue. Please try to check the permission and give the full permission. It should be OK.

Comment: Is your com object 32 or 64 bit, and do your app pool settings correspond?  Also, do your sites have separate IUSR accounts, and if so do they all have the correct permissions on the com object?

Comment: @DanielBlais I have been told by my server admin team that the server is current on all patches.

Comment: @MarkSpencer I agree it sounds like a permission issue, but shouldn't it be using the permission from the user the app pool is running on? It is running on literally the same app pool as a website that is working flawlessly.

Comment: @John both are 32 bit

Comment: If the July patch has been installed then this question is worth reading.  I'm not saying it is where the problem lies, but it's a possibility.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289285/how-do-i-properly-instantiate-32-bit-com-objects-in-classic-asp-after-installing

Comment: @DavidGreilach Please test to give full permission to your folder..